# Is there a way to fill down a list while skipping blanks in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to fill down a list in excel but the data rows have blanks in it and I would like to skip over them, is there a way to do this. The final outcome should look like this - [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRYY1.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Generate Data

[image]

```
=IF(A2="","","Name"&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,"<>"&""))
```

The right example uses [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) in a table (`Table1`).

```
=IF([@INITIAL]="","","Name"&COUNTIF(Table1[[#Headers],[INITIAL]]:[@INITIAL],"<>"&"")-1)
```